# How to convert regular expression when we are using localization in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, ipad

When we are using localization and regular expression in our iphone application. And when we are not using the english language.

Then how to convert that regular expression in relative language.

If i am using below regular expression:

```
+ (BOOL) isAlphabetsOnly:(NSString *) candidate {
    if (![self isEmpty:candidate]) {
        NSString *alphaRegex = @"^\\s*([A-Za-z ]*)\\s*$"; 
        NSPredicate *alphaTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", alphaRegex]; 

        return [alphaTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

It's work fine for the english. But not for other language. Then how can we convert it into other language. So it will work in different language to.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never worked on the iOS but according to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you use something like so: `^\\s*([\\s]*)\\s*$` should work across different locales.

> \w     Match a word character. Word characters are
>   [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}].

Edit: Yes you are correct, my bad. As stated in [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) you should be able to do what you need using the `\p{L}` you should be able to match any letter: 
`^\\s*([\\p{L}\\s]*)\\s*$`

Comment: But when i write expression like this then it will accept all alphabet and numeric values. I want only accept alphabets.

Comment: @SmartDeveloper: Sorry my bad. You are correct. I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your regular expression as a String in the Localizable.strings file.

You could then get it by doing the following:

> NSString
>   *myRegularExpression=NSLocalizedString(@"my_regular_expression",nil);

Comment: I know about the converting the normal sentence into localization. But how can we convert regular expression.